# Why doesn't tomcat see certain folders?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web, browser

In my tomcat webapps directory I have various projects with servlets in them ..

say named test,beer etc

My question is irrespective of the web.xml or contents  when i type localhost:8080/folderName I must be able to view the contents right? but it doesnt work for all folders , for some it says resource not found ,
Example my test folder opens in the browser and my beer folder doesnt , I restarted the browser and tomcat after adding or modifying folders , why can this happen , please explain

Answer (score 1):

My dear friend there is a certain process/configuration/rule that tomcat follows in order to render any web content.It is not some magic happening.
Tomcat has a way of reading web deployments within the /webapp directory.
When we type some URL On the browser tomcat does the following:

Example.

URL : http://localhost:8080/foldername/xyz

Here tomcat takes the part of the URL after http://localhost:8080,that is foldername/xyz.
So here the first part which is foldername means name of the folder present in the /webapps folder.
So reading this tomcat goes inside that folder.Later tomcat is at the mercy of a file called web.xml.All mapping from /foldername/ i.e. /xyz in our case, onwards are present in web.xml.

In your case , if you type http://localhost:8080/foldername/ , tomcat knows that browser refers to webapps/foldername but does not know which resource html/jsp/servlet to forward the request so as to be able to generate a response.

Hence it gives a resource not found exception.

If you want to run the above URL (http://localhost:8080/foldername) then you need to configure a `<welcome-file-list>` tag in the web.xml file.

So for the folders which are working in your case with the above URL, just open their web.xml file and you shall find the `<welcome-file-list>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is what happened

I had a folder test which had some files (NO WEB-INF) , tomcat listed its contents on typing localhost:8080/test

My other folder beer had a WRONG WEB-INF web.xml configuration

So the following is clear to me now

Without a WEB-INF folder and web.xml tomcat will just list the contents of the directory but when you have a WEB-INF and web.xml and something is wrong in them it doesnt even list the directory contents .
Just my understanding of it . 
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using ?

Comment: Doesnt seem to be true.I replicated the example at my end.

Comment: No no try this.... Create a folder named say ...test... Put two pictures in it... Now go to localhost:8080/test it'll list out the contents and show the pictures...... Now do this.... Create a helloworld servlet and create web inf folder etc and put web.xml. now go mess up web. XML. In my case I spelled the servlet tag wrong... Save and restart tomcat.. Now again go to localhost:8080. ... It won't list the contents ...... It'll say resource not found.